# Android - Share custom link via facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I need to share specific part in my app when user open it , if he download my app it navigate direct to this part (it may be nested fragment).

```
String AppURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
String urlToShare = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254"; // I need custom url to specific part in my app 

// See if official Facebook app is found
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
        facebookAppFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

// As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
if (!facebookAppFound) {
    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
}else{

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB: has no effect!
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

here is what I need to approach

[image]

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: I need to share specific fragment via link

Comment: Do you have links for the content that you want to share?

Comment: no I want when he click at link it navigate to specific  fragment in my app

Comment: the approach you needs want facebook sdk to implement. You cannot do it using the android native intent.

Comment: write full answer please

Comment: check my answer please..!!

Answer (score 7):

In order to share the something in Facebook better go with latest Facebook SDK. It will make your task simpler. Because Android Intent has its own restrictions when we use share to facebook. Refer my answer below regarding this

[Share text via Intent on Facebook without using Facebook sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618514/share-text-via-intent-on-facebook-without-using-facebook-sdk/35102802#35102802)

The screenshot that you posted seems to have the sharing of link from the App.

Here is how you will integrate the Facebook SDK to your project.

[Facebook SDK integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Then use the following code to share link on the facebook.

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(Activity.this);
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(act);
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentDescription(
                            "Description")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("your url")).build();
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

More sharing options from Facebook can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android), which is pretty simple and straightforward.

Happy coding..!!

Comment: can I reference activity in my app ? instead of url

Comment: do you want to show your exact page from your app and post it to facebook ?

Comment: yea exactly , when he click at link it navigate to store to download app if not installed , if install open certain page

Comment: then add your play store link in the contentdescription field and share. It will do what you wanted.

Comment: Sharing link is works but issue is that while click on shared link in FB app it should redirect to new page but instead of that it will show error message like "There's problem opening this app".  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
File mFileImagePath = " /storage/emulated/0/Image Editor/Media/FilterImages/Image_Editor_1547816365839.jpg  ";  // Just example you use file URL

private void shareFacebook(File mFileImagePath) {
    String application = "com.facebook.katana";
    boolean installed = checkAppInstall(application);
    if (installed) {
        Intent mIntentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String mStrExtension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(mFileImagePath).toString());
        String mStrMimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(mStrExtension);
        if (mStrExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("") || mStrMimeType == null) {
            // if there is no extension or there is no definite mimetype, still try to open the file
            mIntentShare.setType("text*//*");
        } else {
            mIntentShare.setType(mStrMimeType);
        }
        mIntentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(mFileImagePath));
        mIntentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        mIntentShare.setPackage(application);
        startActivity(mIntentShare);
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Facebook have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private boolean checkAppInstall(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        //Error
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code works for me and will work on all Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ragu Swaninathan, you can use [ShareLinkContent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareLinkContent/)
from Facebook SDK.

Now to achieve the redirection to the specific screen of the app, you can use Firebase [dynamic link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)
feature. You can generate dynamic links using Firebase SDK and then receive those links in the app to handle the navigation flow. You need to share these dynamic links along with the contents.